# Redisson async procesing messages

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, redis, redisson

I'm trying to aply Redisson features for my project as message broker and I have a question. Is it possible to push Redisson to precceding recieved messages asynchronously? I have created a small example, sent 4 messages from different URL's. I expected, that Redisson proceeded them asynchronously, but it did it one by one.
Here the implementation:

```
public class RedisListenerServiceImpl implements MessageListener<String> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisListenerServiceImpl.class);
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void onMessage(CharSequence channel, String stringMsg) {

        log.info("Message received: {}", stringMsg);
        MessageDto msg;
        try {
            msg = objectMapper.readValue(stringMsg, MessageDto.class);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            log.error("Unable to deserialize message: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
            return;
        }

        try {
            //Do my stuff
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Unable to get service from factory: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }
}
```

And the config:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisListenerConfig {

    @Autowired
    public RedisListenerConfig(RedissonClient redisClient,
                               MessageListener redisListenerService,
                               @Value("${redis.sub.key}") String redisSubKey) {

        RTopic subscribeTopic = redisClient.getTopic(redisSubKey);
        subscribeTopic.addListenerAsync(String.class, redisListenerService);
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, may it help - take a look at the multithreaded example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66485053/question-about-the-executors-newsinglethreadexecutor/66485130#66485130

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expected behavior. If you want your messages to be processed concurrently when the Listener **onMessage()** method is triggered, just use a thread pool to process it.

Since Redisson doesn't know how many threads you want to consume the triggered events, it leaves the implementation detail to you.

```
public class RedisListenerServiceImpl implements MessageListener<String> {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisListenerServiceImpl.class);
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

@Override
public void onMessage(CharSequence channel, String stringMsg) {

    log.info("Message received: {}", stringMsg);
    MessageDto msg;
    try {
        msg = objectMapper.readValue(stringMsg, MessageDto.class);
        executorService.submit(()->{
        System.out.println("do something with message: "+msg);
    });
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        log.error("Unable to deserialize message: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        return;
    }

    try {
        //Do my stuff
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Unable to get service from factory: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But if async doesn't mean process messages concurrently, what does it mean?

Comment: @ДанилаКононихин I think here 'async' means non-blockingly. There's a background listener thread monitoring the event for you. It doesn't mean therer are multiple listener threads processing the events concurrently.